# How to view errors/toggle log window in pine script editor?

Tags: debugging, pine-script

Maybe a stupid question. I'm new to TradingView and pine script, so please bear with me if there's some simple way to do this...

I figured out how to copy and modify a script from the library. At first, I could see a tiny edge of a window at the bottom of the script. When I saved or attempted to add the script to the chart, the window showed whether the script processed or had errors.

Now, though, I seem to have "lost" that window. How can I display that window? Also, once displayed, how can I make it larger?

*Edit:*
Here's a screenshot of the bottom of my editor -

[image: Bottom of pine script editor, where log window should appear]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-clicking on the console (errors) window showed a little pop-up saying:

[image: Console right-click menu]

While my cursor is in the editor window, holding Ctrl (or Cmd on a Mac) plus the backtick key toggles the console window open and closed.

Now, I can see the console log window whether I have errors or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can show/hide the pane with pine scripts with the "_" icon on the right side:

[show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56NFJ.png)
[hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmVut.png)

On the rigt side next to the "_" icon you can toggle/maximize the pine script window.

Comment: Thanks, @kittiwake. Those icons show/hide the entire pine script window. I'm looking for the window underneath that shows script errors.

Comment: You can click on "Add to Chart" to redisplay the error messages.

Comment: I've done that, but the error window still isn't coming up. Even when it *was* displaying before, it was just a sliver of a window. But it's not displaying at all now.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the bottom of my editor/browser window: no error log window.

Comment: This error is very frustrating. I somehow lost the console as well, I now there is an error in the code and cannot see where. The consolidate disappeared. and while I can right click on Pine Editor and see "Toggle console", nothing happens after clicking on that.

Answer (score 0):

Add any error to your script and save the script.
In the lower left corner, you will see a small gray triangle.
Drag it up with the mouse.

[image]

Comment: When I purposely added some garbage text, I was able to see the error logging window again. That was the key: when I added the chart *without* any errors, the gray triangle didn't come up. Wow, it would be nice if there were a specific icon on the side, say, or by the editor's maximize/minimize buttons, to open that window. Maybe some feedback their way...

Answer (score 0):

The "Show console" was never visible in my browser. Only the "Toggle console", which did not do anything for me.

I tried a different browser and the console showed well. So I figure it was the browser I was using "Firefox".

So, I re-started Firefox, by going to Un-install Programs in Windows, clicking "Remove program", in front of the Firefox logo, which gave me the choice to restart Firefox. I did took that choice and this fixed the problem for me. I hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox, it may bug and never show it even with the shortcuts (because it becomes a tiny single-line that can't be dragged at the bottom of the page).

In order to fix it without uninstalling firefox: clean the site data for the domain.
[image]